# iTextSharp eliminando documento se não tiver páginas

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Bom, eu tenho uma aplicação que em determinado momento gera um PDF com todos os JPG's, porém, ao invés de escolher um JPG eu escolher um arquivo Excel ele só move esse arquivo.

Certo, eu gostaria que se o documento que eu criei com o iTextSharp (`Doc.Open()` entre outras propriedades) caso não tenha nenhuma página fosse deletado, que não fosse criado, alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Já sei que para saber a quantidade de páginas é `Doc.PageNumber`

```
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A1, 20, 20, 20, 20);
            string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream("C:/AgendaComp/Encaminhamento/" + txtNomePasta.Text + SID.ToString() + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

        Doc.Open();

        string Folder = @"C:/AgendaComp/Encaminhamento/" + txtNomePasta.Text + " arquivos/";
        foreach (string F in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.jpg"))
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(F))
            {
                Doc.NewPage();

                //Doc.PageSize.Height = 1275;
                Doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Jpeg(new Uri(new FileInfo(F).FullName)));
            }
        }
        int n = Doc.PageNumber;
        if (n == 0)
        {
            Doc.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            Doc.Close();
            File.Move("C:/AgendaComp/Encaminhamento/" + txtNomePasta.Text + SID.ToString() + ".pdf", "C:/AgendaComp/Encaminhamento/" + DdataAviso.Year + "-" + DdataAviso.Month + "-" + DdataAviso.Day + "/" + txtNomePasta.Text + SID.ToString() + ".pdf");
        }
```

Comment: poste o código que você está usando ate agora. Provavelmente é possível contar o numero de paginas durante a criação do documento.

Comment: Eu já contei o numero de páginas . Só não consigo fazer com que o documento seja excluido ,ou não criado . Tipo , se ele não tiver nenhuma página , eu não quero que ele exista

Comment: posta o trecho do código que você está utilizando para criar o PDF

Comment: Uma opção é criar o PDF em memória.

Comment: Pronto , adicionei o código , como eu crio ele em memoria ?

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar em memória mude as seguintes linhas:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream("C:/AgendaComp/Encaminhamento/" + txtNomePasta.Text + SID.ToString() + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
```

para

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream);
```

e após fechar o documento

```
 HttpResponse resp = this.Response;
 resp.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```